# Android: How to center the button caption?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a Button like this....

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/mark_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:text="Note"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

It has a fixed size and if I test the App on my phone the text is not getting centered in the button, so the bottom of the text gets cut. Look here :[Picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6843065/IMAG0665.jpg)

Do u have any suggestions?

Comment: i use the standart-android-button... i want this fixed size!

Comment: Use wrap_content in height. And for smaller button use attribute to use small Size.

Comment: I think the font size is too big compared with your fixed height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `wrap_content` for your layout height and use `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"`.
you will get a smaller button, which has a size similar to the size you want:

your code should look like this:

```
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:id="@+id/termin_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+ Termin"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide another background for your button. Currently it is 9-patch, for which some pixels on top marked as unavailable for print-in text (look close at 9-patch tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served by setting the **layout_height** to wrap content. Also try setting the font Size to a lesser "sp" value.